# jQuery check mysql database if username is already taken

Tags: jquery, mysql, validation

i know that this is possible but i am confused as to how it works. I have been looking online for how it is done and I think i am missing something in the process

I have this jQuery code so far:

```
$("#Contact_Info").validate({  
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                remote: "check-username.php"
                }
            },
        messages: {
            username:{
                remote: "This username is already taken! Try another."
            }
        }
  });
```

How should i write my php page to make it talk to the jQuery code?

So far I have:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM T_MEMBER WHERE USERNAME='$name';";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
   return false;
} else
   return true;
```

How do I get the $name variable from the javascript? Do i have to set the "remote" to be POST?

Thanks in advance,
Ian McCullough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP page communicates back to the Javascript just through outputting the data. Depending on the plugin, you could achieve a `true`/`false` by echoing 1 or 0, or perhaps even the string `true` or `false`

The manual says:

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false, undefined or null` for invalid elements

So you can change your PHP to this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $output = true;
} else {
    $output = false;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code on the plugin info page have an example where you can pass data back and forth. Just follow the link below and click the 'examples' tab.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options